# WPF CheckBox is not checked when clicked between text and box

Tags: wpf, checkbox, controltemplate

I have CheckBox with custom style, where the content(text) is shown with 12,0,0,0 margin. So there is the little space between box and text.

[image]

After clicking on a box or text checkBox get's selected,
but when I click on margin space nothing happens.

Does anybody know what where the problem can be?
I would very appreciate any answer.

Answer (score 1):

I found that my custom control template was missing BulletDecorator element.

```
        <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type CheckBox}">
            <BulletDecorator Background="Transparent">
                <BulletDecorator.Bullet>
                    <Grid>
                      . . .
                    </Grid>
                </BulletDecorator.Bullet>
            </BulletDecorator>
            <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="True">
                      . . .
                </Trigger>
            </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
        </ControlTemplate>
```

Answer (score 0):

How are you setting the content of the CheckBox?

The following works fine for me.

```
<CheckBox Grid.Row="0">
    <TextBlock Margin="24,0,0,0" Text="Selected?"/>
</CheckBox>
```

Comment: I am setting the content as usual:      
 

 <CheckBox Grid.Row="0" 
                  Content="Standard"
                  Style="{StaticResource CheckBoxStyle}"/>

Comment: The reason was in my wrong definiton for controlTemplate. It should have BulletDecorator tag

Comment: Check that your style sets the Background property of the CheckBox. If it's null, mouse clicks won't be detected. You can use Transparent instead.